# Jira release version as an input step parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to load a jira release version into a variable using an input step.

```
node {
    def version = input message: 'Approve', parameters: [[$class: 'JiraVersionParameterDefinition', description: 'Select the version', jiraProjectKey: 'APP', jiraReleasePattern: '^1\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)$', jiraShowArchived: 'false', jiraShowReleased: 'false', name: 'version']]
    echo version
}
```

The input shows me a version and I can select it but the result (the variable version) is always null. Is this currently not supported or how is it done?

Comment: What import do you use for using the class JiraVersionParameterDefinition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the JIRA Plugin for Jenkins.

I've created an Issue for that: [JENKINS-45293](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45293)

As a workaround you can use the [JIRA Steps Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Steps+Plugin) (step `jiraGetProjectVersions`) to query the versions and then put them into a choice parameter. Be aware of Bug [JENKINS-40358](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40358) when filling in the choices using the Snippet Generator.